# 1C Soap Web Service

Tags: php, веб-программирование, 1с, soap, веб-служба

Необходимо запустить проект, где есть 1С на СУБД postgreSQL на северной части, и должно быть клиентское, мобильное приложение Android, которое при запросе SOAP получит некую выборку из БД.

Eсть ли какие то ограничения типа max_connection, при запросе на веб-сервис SOAP 1С?

Например, одновременно 50 человек из приложений делают SOAP запрос, есть ли ограничения на одновременный коннект как и при запросе к базе данных?

В данном случае лучше пользоваться SOAP, или можно, например, отдельно прицепиться к postgreSQL, например pgConnect Php, и тягать оттуда данные, а потом в ответ на HTTP запрос отдавать эти данные?

Answer (score 0):

Если речь именно про параллельно выполняемые запросы - то из всех экспериментов народ выяснил что поле пары десятков параллельно выполняющихся запросов начинаются проблемы. Но в целом не очень представляю такую нагрузку на 1с из мобилок. Например у нас был проект с 2к пользователей мобильных приложений с бэкендом на 1с, и все было нормально, хотя да, мы особо запросами не спамили.
Как альтернативный вариант SOAP можете рассмотреть еще появившийся примерно в 8.3.5, или около того, механизм http сервисов. Позволяет реализовать свой рест апи например и гонять по нему хоть плейн текст, хоть жсон, хоть хмл.
Также можете еще посмотреть на OData протокол, его 1с тоже поддерживает, там и вовсе ничего на стороне 1с писать не нужно, но с другой стороны и кастомизировать не выйдет.

Также для оптимизации работы с http и веб-сервисами 1с можно посоветовать еще как минимум 2 вещи:
1) Установить переиспользование сеансов (в свойствах сервиса в конфигураторе 1с). По идее механизм говорит платформе чтобы сеанс пользователя с веб сервера не гасился после окончания http запроса, и какое то время еще висел. Позволяет не инициализировать при каждом запросе параметры сеанса и прочую сопутствующую информацию.

2) Можно посмотреть на тему того какие параметры сеанса для работы веб сервиса не нужны и для веб сервиса инициализировать их вручную например, пустыми значениями. Тоже облегчит установку соединения.

Comment: Могу еще добавить: на постгрю завязываться лучше не надо. Т.е. технически это возможно но: лучше даже не пытаться в базу напрямую писать и никто не гарантирует сохранность таблиц в текущем виде, да и субд заменена может быть (хоть кейс и редкий).